# In R what are the common cases of this error: "Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a 'character'"

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm fighting with a strange problem in R. I use an old version of Rcpp to integrate R with some C++ (sadly upgrading is not an option!), the Rcpp I use is the old RccpTemplate one. However I doubt the problem is in there.

I have some R code which runs fine most of the time, but on occasion (especially when processing a large amount of data) fails mysteriously with `Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a 'character'`

It always fails in list operations, e.g.:

```
res[["blabla"]] = r
```

But if I use `options(error=recover)` and attempt the same after the error, the assignment can be performed with no problems. The C++ only deals with numeric vectors and is actually far away in time an code from the assignments that fail.

So my vague question is: what are the most common causes of such behaviour? Bad memory? Bad objects (perhaps bad `RcppResultSet`)? I'm having troubles attacking this issue...

For completeness:

```
platform       i386-pc-solaris2.10
arch           i386
os             solaris2.10
system         i386, solaris2.10
status
major          2
minor          10.1
year           2009
month          12
day            14
svn rev        50720
language       R
```

Comment: A reproducible example would make it a little easier to help you---which will be difficult anyway as few people still run software versions as dated as yours.

Comment: I wish I had a choice on which software I run :S This problem is rather difficult to reproduce, hence I suspect it has to do with memory corruption of some sort. My question is more along the lines, of have you ever fought with something similar? What ended up being the problem? A bit of guiding in the debugging...

Comment: As you may imagine, my usage does not focus on what we call the deprecated Rcpp API.  As for the error message, I don't think I have ever seen it.  It may have gotten fixed in R as well.

Comment: Well of course the problem is with using the old version. The old API is full of bugs like this. Which is why it has been redesigned from scratch. And we do actually maintain, test and debug new versions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is coming from an error in C code, likely in a package that you are using (not R itself). Either the C code is written incorrectly and you only sometimes evaluate that code branch, or the C code is written incorrectly and it corrupts memory. Likely this requires a C debugger; I'm not sure about Solaris, but on Linux I'd create a script that reliably reproduces the error (this can take some work, but is an essential step) then do

```
R -d gdb
gdb> r # (r)un R
> ^C ## cntrl-C key, breaks into the debugger
gdb> b Rf_error # set breakpoint when error occurs; tab completion available
gdb> c # continue in R
> source("test-script.R") # [error occurs]
gdb> bt  # backtrace -- current call stack, from Rf_error entry
gdb> up  # move up the stack; use this to get to package C code
```

and then it's careful scrutiny of the code, especially looking for mis-use of `PROTECT`. See `gdb help`. I'd strongly suggest updating R and your packages, since bugs do get fixed and you're about to invest a significant amount of time in this.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. In the unlikely case another poor soul will fight with this, my problem was due to using RcppRVector whilst passing a matrix from R. Somehow RcppRVector did not complain but that led to corrupted memory on occasion.

Comment: You are likely to see more of these cryptic errors with the old API.

Comment: I reinstall an R package and it solved the problem.